# ObjectSet and ResultSet on stored procedure on EF and Domain Service

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

In EF 4, the default ObjectSet is available for each entity. For example, I have table Employee, after gererated Entity Model, EF will create ObjectSet on Employee. 
Then when using wcf ria service, the default query will be like:

public IQueryable GetEmployee()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Employees;
    }

With objectSet, I can apply include on the result like:

```
    return this.ObjectContext.Employees.Include("Department");
```

Then I create a stored procedure say MySearchForEmployee and import it as function. the result is mapped to entity Employee. When call the function, the result will be ResultSet, not ObjectSet.

I want to similar method available for domain service by call the stored procedure like:

```
   public IQueryable<Employeer> GetMySearch(string keyword)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.MySearchForEmployee(keyword).Include("Department");
        }
```

But I can't becuase above code event can't pass syntax checking.

I tried following way to convet the result type:

```
 var results = this.ObjectContext.MySearchForEmployee(keyword);
 var objsets = (ObjectSet<Employee>) results;
```

then I got error as:
Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet'

How to implement this request?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use an ObjectSet, because you cannot include multiple entity sets in one query from a stored procedure. This is not supported in the Entity Framework.

You could try the [EFExtensions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) project, it has extensions to load multiple entity sets from one query.

Comment: Thank you. The solution provided by EFExtensions is not what I want. It gives you mutiple result sets from SP, like you have more than one select in your SP. But what I want is get the entityset with all its lookup data. Like Include for ObjectSet. For example, Employee may include 3 lookup table foreign keys: DepartmentID, RoleID, GenderID. I

Comment: What you want is not possible with Entity Framework. Like I said, a stored procedure function import will only return one entity type, and cannot include it's lookup data.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Find out one solution: Loading lookup manually in code.